# Import users from asp.net membership to IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

As the title says:
Is there anyway to import the users (and their passwords!) from the old Membership provider to the new Identity system?

I can see in the old table layout there is a **Password** and **PasswordSalt** column, but in the new IdentityUsers table there is only a **PasswordHash** column. I am hoping there is a way to copy users from the old system to the new one without messing around with creating new passwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [Migrating an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity)